# Не отображается папка приложения в Django

Tags: django, pycharm

Создаю приложение для проекта django при помощи команды:

```
./manage.py startapp products
```

Дело в том, что папка приложения не отображается в проекта в PyCharm, однако в Finder она существует. Ровно то же самое, кстати, происходит и с базой данных db.sqlite3

Скриншот из Finder:
[image: Скриншот из Finder]

Скриншот из PyCharm:
[image: Скриншот из PyCharm]

UPD: Если скопировать и вставить папки из Finder в PyCharm, то они там появляются. Тем не менее, все равно не понятно почему так происходит

Comment: Очень похоже, что вы в одном месте смотрите в папку store, а в pycharm открыли store/store

Comment: К сожалению это не так, папка store на скриншоте из пайчарма раскрыта(то есть должно было быть отражено все содержимое папки) :(

Comment: Попробуйте нажать в меню (клик правой кнопкой по имени главной папки) *Reload from Disk*.

Comment: Вроде это сработало, спасибо большое!